# how to automatically change the url to "&page=1", "&page=2", "&page=3", etc

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to scrape a website that has a url system as follows:

```
http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page=0
http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page=1
http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page=2
```

My intention is to scrape a page, then change the url to the next page, then scrape, then next page, and so on.

My faulty script is as follows:

```
driver.get('http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page=0')
while True:
    #code for scraping information

    #code to get to next page
    i=0
    while (f'http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page={i}')
        i+=1
    driver.get(f'http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page={i}')
```

Does anyone know what I should be doing?

The exception is:

```
  File "<input>", line 45
    while (f'http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page={i}')
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have simplified the entire script, and added print strings to see where the script hangs.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.ozbargain.com.au/?page=0')
while True:
    print('sleeping for 5 secs')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('proceeding')

    #code to get to next page
    i=0
    print('i=0 added')
    while (f'https://www.ozbargain.com.au/?page={i}'):
        i+=1
    print('while loop finished')
    driver.get(f'https://www.ozbargain.com.au/?page={i}')
    print('end of loop')
```

and I get this:

```
sleeping for 5 secs
proceeding
i=0 added
```

So obviously the embeded while loop is faulty.

Comment: how are you exiting from `while` loop? what error are you getting right now?

Comment: I added the exception. I plan on breaking loop when the text scraped matches certain text from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `:` at the end of your while statement,
it should be,

```
while (f'http://www.website.com/browse.php?cat=19&s_tag=1&page={i}'):
```

Comment: The colon fixed the exception, but the loop gets stuck after the scrape is done, but before any url is changed.

Comment: it will be easier to troubleshoot if you can show entire code

Comment: well the website requires a login and password, so I can't share that. I have replaced the scraping part of the code with a time.sleep(5), and it's still not working.

Comment: anyway, I added a simplified script, which shows that the script hangs at the embeded while loop.

Comment: your while loop are not finishing

Comment: how do I finish it?

Comment: you need to break out of the loop if certain condition is met, like `if i == 10: break`

Comment: Oh I think you misunderstood my intention with the code. The while loop with the "i" is supposed to change the url to the next number. So in the above code, the current page is 0, and it will sleep for 5 seconds, and then take me to page 1, then sleep for 5 seconds, and then take me to page 2, then sleep for 5 seconds, etc.